# How to make Command prompt on Windows 10 to display files and folders in different colours?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I want to see more colourful output in a Command prompt(**cmd.exe**) on Windows, like in linux shell: folders coloured in one colour, different files in another and so one..

I want like that:

[screenshot Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqwO7.png)

[screenshot on linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2kOg.png)

Comment: You say command prompt, but you show a screenshot of Powershell. Which is it? If it's command prompt, use `color /?` to learn about how to change the colours.

Comment: The latter screenshot shows the output from `ls`. Do you just want `ls.exe` with color support in Windows?

Comment: I want %windir%\system32\cmd.exe to display more colourful output

Comment: Short answer. It's not possible.

Comment: Its possible with Microsofts Color Tool>>>>https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-command-prompts-color-scheme-windows-10

Comment: You can also just use the bash shell from a WSL instance.  Windows programs run just fine from it.